# Exterior Algebra with Jets instead of Forms?

Tags: differential-forms, exterior-algebra, de-rham-cohomology, jet-bundles

For a smooth, $n$-dimensional manifold $M$ over $\mathbb{R}$, I would like to know if sections of the dual space of the order-$k$ jet bundle sit within a commutative differential graded algebra structure. I'm imagining that this would restrict to the De-Rham complex when $n = 1$.

More specifically, for order $n$, what I am naïvely imagining is something like $C^\infty(M) \otimes \Lambda( dx^I)$, where $I$ ranges over all multi-indices $I = (I_1, I_2, \ldots, I_n) \in \mathbb{N}^n $ where $\sum I_j < k$ and $dx^I$ is the 'dual' of the section
$$ \dfrac{\partial^{\sum I_j}}{dx_1^{I_1}\ldots dx_n^{I_n}}$$
of the order-$k$ jet bundle. My guess is the exterior derivative in degree $0$ would just sum up over all the $<k$-th order partials, then be extended via the Leibniz rule.

Does anyone know

- if there is an obvious problem with this idea, or if there exists something like this that has been well studied?
- if it computes singular cohomology of the manifold, like the De-Rham case.

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the commutative product here? The dual vector bundle of the $k$-jets $J^k(M,\mathbb{R})$ can be naturally identified with the bundle of order $\le k$ linear partial differential operators $D_{\le k}(C^\infty M,C^\infty M)$. These form a associative graded algebra under composition, but it is not commutative.

Comment: Hmm, I hadn't realised that the natural algebra structure for dual $k$-jets was composition. Is there no other algebra structure that reduces to the wedge product when we take dual $1$-jets?

Comment: There are of course other (perhaps non-canonical) algebra structures, but I'm not sure what you mean by the wedge product: we can of course canonically identify $J^1M\cong (M\times\mathbb{R})\oplus_M T^*M$ but taking a wedge product would give an element of $(M\times\mathbb{R})\oplus_M T^*M\oplus_M\Lambda^2T^*M$, and I'm not sure how you would identify alternating tensor bundles like $\Lambda^2T^*M$ with jet bundles. Also, the wedge product is *anti*commutative, not commutative.